# Error: Required named parameter 'path' must be provided

Tags: flutter

im getting below errors in my code. how to solve this. appreciate your help on this

> Error: Required named parameter 'path' must be provided.
> Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (builder)=>
> CameraViewPage()));
>
> Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.   const
> CameraViewPage({Key? key, required this.path}) : super(key: key);
>
> Error: Too many positional arguments: 0 allowed, but 1 found. Try
> removing the extra positional arguments.    await
> _cameraController.takePicture(path);

CameraSreen.dart

```
  void takePhoto(BuildContext context) async {
   final path = join((await getTemporaryDirectory()).path,"${DateTime.now()}.png");
   await _cameraController.takePicture(path);
   Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (builder)=> CameraViewPage()));
  }
```

CameraView.dart

```
class CameraViewPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const CameraViewPage({Key? key, required this.path}) : super(key: key);
  final String path;
```

Comment: You need to pass path compulsory other wise remove required before this.path and add ? in String like String? path;

Comment: await _cameraController.takePicture(path); getting an error in word path of this line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see:

```
CameraViewPage({Key? key, required this.path}) : super(key: key);
```

The argument `path` is required.

So this is how you should call `Navigator.push`:

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (builder)=> CameraViewPage(path: path)));
```

If you read the error message about `takePicture`, it says you shouldn't pass any POSITIONAL parameter. Without any more details, I assume `takePicture` takes a NAMED parameter `path`. Try:

```
await _cameraController.takePicture(path: path);
```

Comment: await _cameraController.takePicture(path);  getting an error in word path of this line

Comment: Edited my answer. See above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this you have made path as required argument for CameraViewPage class so you are not passing path while navigating to next screen.

```
  void takePhoto(BuildContext context) async {
       final path = join((await getTemporaryDirectory()).path,"${DateTime.now()}.png");
       await _cameraController.takePicture(path);
       Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (builder)=> CameraViewPage(path:path)));
      }
```

Comment: Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.  await _cameraController.takePicture(path);  now im getting this error related to path , mention code.